# wix uninstall dialog properties not updating

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am launching a custom dialog in my uninstall sequence to gather a handful of data items from the user ultimately to run a custom action to undo an install time custom action. unfortunately none of the property values from the UI are being updated...? They are all blank when I get to my custom action code.

I have read most of the related posts on the web, and I understand not many people are doing uninstall dialogs, being that it will not show in the add/remove version of the uninstaller, and the possibility of getting around this using the `ARPNOREMOVE`, etc...

Considering I do want to use the uninstall dialog, why aren't the properties being updated? I added the dialog to the install time sequence and the properties are there in the custom action, so I don't believe it is a configuration problem with my dialog or properties. What is different about the UI -properties in the uninstall?

Comment: Is the custom action being called again on uninstall? Windows Installer does not save properties from install. Probably a stupid question but it happened me...:)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of problems:

1. The properties are not public (app caps names). Only public properties are passes to the execution phase of the installation. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Your custom action runs deferred and it does't have access to the installation context. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to access context data from a deferred ca.

Comment: hi yan, thanks. all my properties are indeed public and the custom action is running as immediate. as a test, i rewired my installer to show the dialog and run the custom action during install, and everything worked fine - i was able to read the properties set in the dialog. but something must be different about how the properties/dialogs work during uninstall...still stumped...

Comment: create a log durring uninstall. that should show what happens to the pops values